# Translating a cURL request to PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

The cURL request I am trying to translate is similar to this:

```
curl -0 -XPOST -u user:pass --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"retrieve_summary_info","params":[true, 10],"id":1}' http://127.0.0.1:3141/v2/owner
```

I want to send this with php and then display the json response but am not sure how I would translate that to PHP

Comment: This is not a code-writing site; unless you have a _specific_ question about a _specific_ issue with code _you have already written_, we won't really be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$ch   = curl_init();
$data = "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"retrieve_summary_info\",\"params\":[true, 10],\"id\":1}";
$user = ''; // set your user
$pass = ''; // set your password

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:3141/v2/owner');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$user}:{$pass}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Check this [website](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/), it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:3141/v2/owner');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"retrieve_summary_info\",\"params\":[true, 10],\"id\":1}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user' . ':' . 'pass');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```